# Calling a Function (Javascript) from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript popup dialog box but is unable to utilize it within my php code. I tried everything I could think of but nothing works below is an example code snippet:

```
<?php
    $password = "sysadmin";

    if( isset( $_POST[ 'signin' ] ) )
    {
        if( $password == 'sysadmin' )
        {
            echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>msgAlert( 'Congrats', 'Access Granted' );</script>";
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test for Javascript Function Call</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action = "" method = "POST">
            <button name "signin" type = "submit">Sign In</button>
        </form>

        <script type = "text/javascript">
            function msgAlert( title, text )
            {
                alert( title + " : " + text );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the code above is just a sample test, if I can get the code above to work maybe I can to call a boostrap javascript popup dialogbox cause it is really boring to use the default *window.alert()* dialog box.  So what is wrong with the code? why is it not calling the necessary function? what should I do to be able to get the code running smoothly.

on a side note, please no need to downpoint my question.  This question may be redundant/stupid/annoying/unimportant and whatever to you, but I am new to web development so it is pretty much important to me...thanks for the help

Comment: Try putting your php with the function call after the actual function. So have the `<?php ... ?>` tag below the `<script>...</script>` tag. Or just put the php tag inside of the `<script>` tag. I think the browser is loading the function call first, then executing it and failing, and only after that loading the actual function

Comment: Just look at the resulting HTML. 1) You have a `script` element *before* the `<html>`. 2) You're trying to call `msgAlert` before you have defined it. – This issue has nothing much to do with PHP, it's simply wrong Javascript/HTML in what you're producing here.

Comment: thanks @Doc I learned something new helped me big time

Comment: thanks also @deceze I understand your points and it taught me something new really helped

Answer (score 1):

Theres another mistake in your js code:
You try to call the function before the dom is loaded. That may causes the problem. Do sth like this in your js:

```
window.onload=function(){msgAlert("test");};
```

Comment: thanks it is a thought but not exactly the direction I am going....but I learned something big help

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the Javascript function inside php tags.  Otherwise the Javascript function call will go out of scope.  here's an example. N:B the code is not tested.

```
<?php
    $password = "sysadmin";
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'signin' ] ) )
        {
            if( $password == 'sysadmin' )
                {

                    echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>
function msgAlert( title, text )
            {
                alert( title + ' : ' + text );
            }msgAlert( 'Congrats', 'Access Granted' );</script>";
                }
        }
?>
   <!-- remaining html -->
```

Comment: noped didnt work also I don't think that is an advisable way to call a javascript function